# How can I select records from yesterday's day from 12 AM to 6 AM and from 11 PM to 12 AM in oracle sql developer?

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

EX:if yesterday's date is 19th we need to show the records for 19th 12AM to 6 AM and 11 PM to 12 AM.

the query which i tried.Please suggest me.

```
select * from table_name 
where TIMESTAMP between trunc(sysdate-1) and 
trunc(sysdate-1) + 6/24 
or timestamp between trunc(sysdate-1) + 23/24 and 
trunc(sysdate);
```

Comment: Performance tuning is a complicated task which requires specific information. How many records in the whole table? How many records in the given 7 hour window? Is the timestamp column indexed? Is the table partitioned with a key which aligns with the timestamp column?

Comment: I mean could you make it some what easier to get the result in less time

Comment: Not until you answer those questions, and maybe not even then. Tuning is a science not a magical art.

Comment: Nobody can answer this question until you provide the further details. This is entirely in your hands.

Answer (score 1):

You may need:

```
where yourColumn between trunc(sysdate -1) + 23/24 and trunc (sysdate) + 6/24
```

How it works: `sysdate` both contains date and time informations, so `trunc(sysdate)` only keeps day, with no hours, minutes, ....

If you add a number to a date, that number is meant to represent days, so 1/24 gives one hour and so on.

For clarity:

```
trunc(sysdate)           ->  today at 00:00 AM
trunc(sysdate-1)         ->  yesterday at 00:00 AM
trunc(sysdate-1) +  6/24 ->  yesterday at 06:00 AM
trunc(sysdate-1) + 18/24 ->  yesterday at 06:00 PM
...
```

Comment: @Ravin  :   SELECT * FROM table_name where yourColumn between trunc(sysdate -1) + 23/24 and trunc (sysdate) + 6/24

Comment: If i want to select for yesterday 11 PM to 12 AM and 12 AM to 6 AM.how can i add that.please suggest me.

Comment: 11pm to 12 am? and 12am to 6 am? today it's 2018-07-20 ... what do you need?

Comment: not for today the data should i get for yesterday only.The above query is taking long time `select * from table_name where TIMESTAMP between trunc(sysdate-1) and trunc(sysdate-1) + 6/24 or timestamp between trunc(sysdate-1) + 23/24 and trunc(sysdate);`

Comment: could you please optimize the above query as it is taking more time to get the result ?

Comment: @Ravin - The query you just posted in the comment appears to retrieve a different set of data from the one you post in your question. It would be helpful if you could clarify what records you actually want, using sample dates and with times specified using 24-hour clock.

Comment: if yesterday's date is 19th we need to show the records for 19th 12AM to 6 AM and 11 PM to 12 AM.I need to get this records for that I have tried with  this query .`select * from table_name where TIMESTAMP between trunc(sysdate-1) and trunc(sysdate-1) + 6/24 or timestamp between trunc(sysdate-1) + 23/24 and trunc(sysdate); `.But it is taking more time to execute.Can you make it some simpler to get the result in less time.

Comment: Please **edit your question** with this actual requirement, which is different from what you originally asked. Most people will read your question, not a long thread of comments. Also, please provide the additional information I asked for.